# validating textbox in windows form applications

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, spaces

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [validating textbox in windows form applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987924/validating-textbox-in-windows-form-applications)
>   [validating textbox in windows form application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987286/validating-textbox-in-windows-form-application)

The Event not allowing Any Spaces ,
But i want Avoid start one or two or three Spaces in text box in windows form application using C#.net

```
void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
}
```

Comment: Hey you should be editing the previous question with additional data rather than asking it again and again

Comment: "But i want Avoid start one or two or three Spaces" what?

Comment: Can you show us any dummy data what input & output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Even the edited question is really hard to make sense of. So I'm going to guess that you meant to say: "I want to avoid a textbox starting with 1,2 or 3 spaces"

In the TextChanged event use String.Trim, or use Replace(" ",string.empty), or if its critical for a max of 3 spaces use a for loop and only remove the spaces with String.Substring