# validating textbox in windows form applications

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, spaces

My scenario is:

Not allowing spaces at starting position of textbox after enter one or more characters  text box allows spaces

Below not applicable to my scenario.

1. ```
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Spaces are not allowed");
       }
   }
   ```
2. ```
   textBox1.Text.TrimStart()
   ```

Comment: can you give some more details? why don't the two methods you mentioned apply?

Comment: And This is from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987286/validating-textbox-in-windows-form-application

Comment: Why you are repeating the same question again and again

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) \
{ 
if(textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    if (e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)) 
        { 
        MessageBox.Show("Spaces are not allowed at start"); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that lazyDBA's answer is correct for your requirements, so with the message box something like:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
{
   if (e.Handler = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))
   {
       MessageBox.Show("space not allowed!");
   }  
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)         
 {             
     if (e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))             
     {                 
        if(((TextBox)sender).Text.Replace(" ","") == "")
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Spaces are not allowed");  
             ((TextBox)sender).Text = string.Empty;
        }           
     }          
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `KeyPress` event

```
if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length <= 0)
    e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
else
    e.Handled = false;
```

In case you have to make it work also in case if the user after typing in some text moves to the start of the `TextBox` field and attempts to enter space then this will disable that too

```
void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if ((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart == 0)
          e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
     else
          e.Handled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say option number one is not applicable.  How about a version of option number one that uses the same event and similar code but inside a second IF statement.  This keeps spaces from working unless there are other characters in the text box.

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
{
 e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not described briefly and if I am not wrong you wanted to trim the spaces at beginning right ?

then my answer is, you can handle it many way and one possible way is to handle this in the following way also. Some sample code I have written here in below, you can check with that, its running perfectly in my sample application:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((textBox1.SelectionStart == 0) && (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           //Store the back up of Current Cursor Possition.
           int cusorpos = textBox1.SelectionStart;

           if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
           {
                 if (textBox1.Text[0] == ' ')
                 {
                       //Trim Spaces at beginning.
                       textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimStart(' ');

                       //Set the Cursor position to current Position. 
                       textBox1.SelectionStart = cusorpos;
                  }
           }
    }
```

as you can see here i wrote two events its because if any body paste a text with spaces at beginning, in your textbox control then it will work perfectly to remove the spaces from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the regex

```
        string strRegex = @"^([\w]+.*)$";
        string strTargetString =  textBox1.Text;

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(strTargetString, strRegex))
        {
            // show error that spase not allow at the bigin of string
        }
```