# I want to remove any leading spaces within a TextBox in my windows forms application using .net

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, spaces

not allowing first character as spaces after textbox allow spaces in windows form application
like

```
       textbox1.text="   fg";  //----------- not like
       textbox1.text="vcvc   hfh"; //------------Like this
```

Answer (score 5):

You could place this code in the `TextChanged` event or `OnKeyDown` event (or you could use it whenever you want)

```
string myString = textBox1.Text.TrimStart()
```

or even straight to the point

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimStart()
```

Comment: I had already mentioned this but the OP didn't like it ..oops he deleted that question ! [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987924/validating-textbox-in-windows-form-applications/5988004#5988004)

Answer (score 3):

This will avoid space at the start of the textbox1

```
void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if ((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart == 0)
          e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
     else
          e.Handled = false;
}
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987924/validating-textbox-in-windows-form-applications/5988004#5988004)

Comment: What if whitespace was copy and pasted in to the text box?

Comment: well then you will have to check the `TextChanged` in that case

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regular expression to remove leading white space by substituting the leading white space with an empty string (""). In this example, "     Hello     " would become "Hello     ":

```
String result = Regex.Replace(textbox1.text, "^[ \t\r\n]", "");
```

Similarly, you could strip trailing white space. In this example, "     Hello     " would become "     Hello":

```
String result = Regex.Replace(textbox1.text, "[ \t\r\n]+$", "");
```

If you use the pipe operator ( "|" ), you can give both patterns in the same expression to strip both leading and trailing white space. This is the particular one I use in my C# project. It is the .NET equivalent to the Perl *chomp* command. In this example, "     Hello     " would become "Hello":

```
String result = Regex.Replace(textbox1.text, "^[ \t\r\n]+|[ \t\r\n]+$", "");
```

For a slew of really great tutorial, examples, and reference information on .NET regular expressions, see this site:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Note: To use regular expressions in C#, you must add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to the top of your C# file.

Note also: If you prefer, you can substitute `[ \t\r\n]` for the `[\s]` white space operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just Trim() the text when you're ready to use it?

Answer (score 0):

To Remove All Space in your Text Even in Start, Middle or End

Here's my Code

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

txtAfter.Text = Regex.Replace(txtBefore.Text, " ", "");
```

Comment: Any idea of why did you chose to use Regex.Replace instead of String.Replace?

Answer (score -1):

You could test to see if the key down is the spacebar, or trim it. Perhaps.